# JavaScript for Chrome extension - get Windows username

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, windows-authentication

I am working on a Chrome extension, where in my JavaScript function should identify the logged in Windows username.

I want to access Windows' username within JavaScript and display it in my Chrome extension web page.

I tried following `<script>`, this works well in IE. Is there any equivalent way possible with the Chrome browser?

```
function GetUserName()
    {
        var wshell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        alert(wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%"));
    }
```

Please let me know any built-in method to extract the username.

Comment: You can write an [NPAPI plugin](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html). If given full permissions, it can do whatever a regular app can, and you can expose its capabilities as JavaScript object. Look around StackOverflow to find out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're using ActiveX which is only available in IE**.  In my opinion you should never be able to access information like this from within a browser (and usually can't). I doubt there is a solution which functions like you want.

Comment: My question is - what method i can use to implement the same in Chrome?

Comment: Like I say - I sincerely doubt you can

Comment: Thank you, but what are the ways to authorize a person. I dont have much knowledge about OAuth and OpenID.

Comment: You're going to have to go down the route of something over HTTP, look at the way websites do it.